# Movimentar dados de uma página para outra por meio de um botão no Ionic 4

Tags: ionic

Em um cenário onde tenho uma tela inicial com um "ion-input" e um botão. Quando inserir o código no input e clicar no botão, quero ser redirecionado para outa pagina e, quero que nessa outra página, seja exibido o valor digitado na página anterior, seria possível?

Observação, o código digitado deve ser guardado em um objeto instanciado na primeira página.

Alguém sabe como fazer?

Comment: Cara, com Angular você poderia fazer usando as rotas, não sei se ficaria gambiarroso no seu caso. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vA49SLthZUw .
Pesquisando sobre isso no Ionic 3, achei esse link que pode te ajudar tbm : 
https://medium.com/@programadriano/ionic-3-passando-valores-entre-as-p%C3%A1ginas-c816e4d34191

Comment: Olá, já solucionei, muito simples. Basta adicionar na sua rota, no Path, o nome da página + parâmetro:
`{path: "new-item/:id"}` e depois no tamplate chamar assim:  `<ion-input type="text" name="ticket" [(ngModel)]="ticket"></ion-input>
      <ion-button [routerLink]="['/new-item', ticket]">Confirmar</ion-button>`

Comment: Que massa cara, posta como sua resposta e depois marca como solucionado para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: Você pode marcar sua própria resposta como resolução da sua pergunta dois dias depois de publicar, isso faz com que o quadradinho ao lado da sua pergunta fique verde.